# How to write a vector with a pair of ints as key and int as value in c++?

Tags: c++11, vector, syntax, int, std-pair

I am new to programming, just started learning hashing.
I tried to find out - like map - how can we assign a `pair` of `int`s as key and an `int` as value in a vector.

On searching i did find `vector` of `pair` where `first` element of `pair` is key and `second` element of pair as value but i need a way to make "`pair of int`" as KEY and an `int` as VALUE.

I felt a need of this as i needed to sort a `pair` of `int` with respect to their value. Any suggestion?

Comment: Just do it. What exactly is blocking you?

Comment: i couldnt find  the  syntax to do that.

Comment: how to copy pair as key and int as value from map to vector and then sort the vector of pair and int with respect to value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may declare such `vector` as following:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::pair<int,int>, int>> vec;
```

Then push the elements as below:

```
vec.push_back(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(1,2), 3));
```

See the [demo](https://ideone.com/LwLzoL).

---

However, if you want to find particular elements, then I would advise to use `std::map` rather than the `std::vector`. Remember that `std::map` will always be sorted. However, since the `std::pair` is a key, you may have to provide a custom comparator.